# PHP write outside document root

Tags: php, permissions

I'm trying to create a file in a directory outside the document root of the web server. The folder has permissions 777 but php says Permission Denied:
Warning: fopen(/home/site2/public_html/images/x.jpg) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/site1/public_html/test_sites.php on line 2
Permission problem

```
<?php
$f = fopen('/home/site2/public_html/images/x.jpg', 'wb');

if(!$f) die("Permission problem");

fclose($f);
echo "OK";
?>
```

Comment: `public_html` doesnt sound exactly like it is *outside document root*. Also you do not want any folders to be world writable (777) unless you want your security to go to 666.

Answer (score 2):

The 777 permissions is half the battle. You will also need to change the group to be www-data (if on debian) using the:

`chgrp g+w www-data /home/growtent/public_html/images`

That "should" work, depending on what system you are running and given that my memory is correct.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like [safe mode](http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/ini.sect.safe-mode.php#ini.safe-mode) is on and [doc_root](http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.doc-root) has been set. You'll need to set `doc_root` to empty or turn off safe mode.