# writing files to a different directory

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP write outside document root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313779/php-write-outside-document-root)

assume I have a script in somewhere in the htdocs directory and I want this script to write files in a directory that is of the same parent as htdocs. how do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Your *htdocs* represents your [docroot](http://docs.karelia.com/z/Document_Root.html).

Reading from [the PHP manual for the php.ini file](http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.doc-root):

> doc_root
>
> PHP's "root directory" on the server.
>   Only used if non-empty. If PHP is
>   configured with safe mode, no files
>   outside this directory are served. If
>   PHP was not compiled with
>   FORCE_REDIRECT, you should set
>   doc_root if you are running PHP as a
>   CGI under any web server (other than
>   IIS). The alternative is to use the
>   cgi.force_redirect configuration
>   below.

Check if you're working in safe mode. Also check the permissions for the folder you're writing to. They should allow writing for the server-user (www, www-data, whatever).

Finally, this question might be [a duplicate of this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313779/php-write-outside-document-root).